# Switching between wrapfigure and figure environments

Tags: environments, wrapfigure, environment-variables

I'm trying to realise switching between `wrapfigure` and `figure` environments, using boolean control. But for some reason wrapfigure does not do what it should do - be wrapped, instead it is placed in the end of the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{Figure} 
\setboolean{Figure}{true}

\newenvironment{WrapFigure}[3]
{
\ifthenelse{\boolean{Figure}}{\begin{wrapfigure}[#1]{#2}{#3}}{\begin{figure}}   
        }
        {   
\ifthenelse{\boolean{Figure}}{\end{wrapfigure}}{\end{figure}}       
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{WrapFigure}{14}{r}{0.35\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[draft,width=0.38\linewidth]{NICE Figure.pdf}
    \caption{XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX }
\end{WrapFigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a group around `wrapfigure`, that makes it choke.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newboolean{Figure} 
\setboolean{Figure}{true}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{WrapFigure}{omm}
 {%
  \ifFigure
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {\wrapfloat{figure}{#2}{#3}}
      {\wrapfloat{figure}[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
  \else
    \figure
  \fi
 }
 {%
  \ifFigure
    \endwrapfloat
  \else
    \endfigure
  \fi
 }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{WrapFigure}[14]{r}{0.35\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[draft,width=0.38\linewidth]{NICE Figure.pdf}
    \caption{XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX }
\end{WrapFigure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

(the `\ifFigure` syntax is simpler, in this case, I believe). With `xparse` it's easy to keep the syntax of `wrapfig`.

[image]